# Can't connect from EC2 to RDS via PHP. I can directly thought

Tags: mysql, php, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I've set up an EC2 instance it has mysql and php-mysql installed (not mysql-server).

I've set up an RDS instance and set the security group to the EC2 instance.

I *can* connect via the command line from the EC2, but when I try connecting via mysqli I get the message: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXXX.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com'

This is my first time working with both.

Am I missing something here?

```
define("HOST", "XXXX.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com");
define("DBUSER", "my_user");
define("PASS", "********");
define("DB", "mydb");
define("PORT", 3306);

$link=mysqli_connect(HOST,DBUSER,PASS,DB,PORT); 

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($link)){
    echo "Failure to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: What is the complete command you are entering at the shell prompt?

Comment: mysql -h XXXX.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u my_user -p

Comment: You're not specifying a database in that command.  Are you sure it's the entire command?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't connect to a specific DB but I WAS able to connect to the RDS server. However if I try the same via mysqli I'm getting "can't connect to server"

Comment: Try connecting with the database. Your user probably hasn't been given specific permission to access that database.

Comment: Tried that, I can connect via shell directly to db. not via php. "Cannot connect to MySQL server"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407281/mysqli-connect-problem).

The solution was to run `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1`

Answer (score 0):

I had to make changes for SELinux, my instance was RHEL6.

`setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db on`

What I found odd was that SELinux logged nothing unusual to `/var/log/audit/audit.log`

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

I removed the port specification in my DSN.
Managed to connect form EC2 to RDS then.

Link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955446/sqlstatehy000-2005-unknown-mysql-server-host-mysql1-alwaysdata-com3306-2